# vlookup to search data using a table for search terms and returning a result from the array

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I have a long document (10k+ lines) and I'm trying to sort it out into records or tables with 10 data types for each record. Each data type can be identified by having one or more keywords (case sensitive).

I started building a nested IF statement but it quickly became very difficult to figure out what I was even looking at.

I built a second table with one column of data type names and added the keywords thinking I could use a vlookup to match the keywords and return the field name but I'm having trouble understanding how to get vlookup to do that.

Am I going about this all wrong?

see above

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("ABJURATION", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("CONJURATION", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("DIVINATION", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("ENCHANTMENT", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("EVOCATION", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("ILLUSION", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("NECROMANCY", B2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("TRASMUTATION", B2)),), "Traits", "")

I wants hundreds of records sorted out into ten columns based on data type

Comment: Please add a sample picture containing the original data and what you expect the result to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro

```
Option Explicit

Sub find_words()
Dim arr()
Dim i#, k#, Laste_Ro#
'complete this array as you want
arr = Array("ABJURATION", "CONJURATION", "ENCHANTMENT", _
      "EVOCATION", "ILLUSION", "TRASMUTATION")
    Laste_Ro = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Row
     Rem =====>>Change Sheet1 by the sheet's name
     For i = 2 To Laste_Ro
        For k = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Cells(i, 2) Like "*" & arr(k) & "*" Then
            Cells(i, 3) = "Traits"
            End If
         Next
     Next

End Sub
```